# Executing .exe from Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6, exe, shellexecute

I'm new to visual basic. I'm trying to execute `.exe` file from VB. But I'm not getting the output. My `.exe` is having command line args. Following is my code

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Shell "D:\FEP\extractFEPData.exe data.txt", vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

In cmd prompt If I give command `extractFEPData.exe data.txt` It is parsing the file. But in VB after clicking command button nothing happens.

Please help me.

Answer (score 6):

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
                    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                    ByVal lpOperation As String, _
                    ByVal lpFile As String, _
                    ByVal lpParameters As String, _
                    ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
                    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Private Const SW_HIDE As Long = 0

Private Const SW_SHOWNORMAL As Long = 1

Private Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED As Long = 3

Private Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED As Long = 2


Private Sub Label1_Click()

    ShellExecute Me.hwnd, "Open", "G:\PN Technologies\VB\Krishna & Co\KrishnaCo.exe", vbNullString, "C:\", SW_SHOWNORMAL

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

In the past I've always used the [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx) Win32 API. You can find a great references on using it from VB6 below.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238245

http://www.vbaccelerator.com/codelib/shell/shellex.htm

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you want to capture the output)

You need to use some .NET functions (see [here](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_run_dos.html)) if you are using VB.NET
or some win32 API (see [here](http://ttp://randomconsultant.blogspot.com/2010/07/run-command-and-read-console-output-in.html)) if you are using VB6.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to set the current directory? You are only passing the file name, not a full path.

```
ChDrive "d:" 
ChDir "d:\fep" 
Shell "D:\FEP\extractFEPData.exe data.txt", vbNormalFocus
```

[VB6 Manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243256(VS.60).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the WShell.Exec method to run the program and return a WshScriptExec object that has a StdOut property which is a TextStream object you can read.

This can be a little clunky since it only supports blocking calls.  However you can use API calls to run the external process and redirect its standard I/O streams to anonymous pipes that the VB6 program can read from/write to.  This is more work but you get more control.

Perhaps you are looking for something else though?